# Mathematical foundation of "sample_weight" in XGBoost and TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, xgboost

I have looked around for some concrete sources about what this feature does. From my understanding what "sample_weight" does is add an extra constant term on the second derivative of the cost function (to optimize the networks weights for best results). Which simply "tells" the network that one sample is less/more important than others.

This is a very simple ambiguous explanation, so I was wondering what the actual mathematical expression is for these weights.